# Ayuda sobre programar ls-l en c violacion de segmento

Tags: c

Llevo como loco con este programa que estoy haciendo en `c` y no consigo que me funcione bien. Lo que estoy haciendo es implementar en `c` dos comandos un `ls-x` y un `ls-l` cuando lo pruebo con el directorio "." , me funciona todo y cuando lo pruebo con cualquier otro directorio diferente, el `ls-l` me sale violación de segmento, si me pudieseis guiar. Os copio el código.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "util.h"

void lsx(DIR *dirp){
    printf("ls -x\n");
    struct dirent *direntp;
    while ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
        if(strncmp(direntp->d_name, ".", 1)!=0||strncmp(direntp->d_name, "..", 1)!=0){
        printf("%s\t",direntp->d_name); 
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    closedir(dirp);
}
void lsl(DIR *dirq){
    printf("ls -l\n");
    struct dirent *direntp;
    struct stat otra;
    struct passwd *pass;
    struct tm      *tm;
    struct group   *grp;
    while ((direntp = readdir(dirq)) != NULL) {
        if(strncmp(direntp->d_name, ".", 1)!=0||strncmp(direntp->d_name, "..", 1)!=0){
            stat(direntp->d_name, &otra);//Actualizamos el estado de los ficheros
            /* Realizamos los permisos del fichero con la estructura stat */
            printf( (S_ISDIR(otra.st_mode)) ? "d" : "-" );
            printf( (otra.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-" );
            printf( (otra.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-" );
            printf( (otra.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-" );
            printf( (otra.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-" );
            printf( (otra.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-" );
            printf( (otra.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-" );
            printf( (otra.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-" );
            printf( (otra.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-" );
            printf( (otra.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-" );
            printf("%-8.8s\t");
            /* Realizamos el nombre del propietario del fichero con la estructura passwd */
            pass=getpwuid(otra.st_uid);
            printf("%-8.8s\t",pass->pw_name);
            /* Realizamos el nombre del grupo del fichero con la estructura group */
            grp = getgrgid(otra.st_gid);
                printf("%-8.8s\t", grp->gr_name);
            /* Realizamos la ultima fecha de modificacion del fichero con la estructura tm */       
            printf("%s\t", ctime(&otra.st_mtime));
            printf("%s\n",direntp->d_name);
        }
    }
closedir(dirq);
}

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "util.h"


int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argv[1]==NULL){//Si no pasamos por argumentos tomamos el directorio que en el que nos encontramos
        lsx(opendir("."));
        lsl(opendir("."));
    }else{
        lsx(opendir(argv[1]));
        lsl(opendir(argv[1]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Me parece que el fallo está en como obtienes el `DIR *` que pasas como argumento a las funciones `readdir`. ¿ Como lo obtienes ? No es lógico que el código falle como comentas. ¿ Porqué no compruebas `dirq` en las funciones que usas ?

Comment: Yo diría que la etiqueta es incorrecta,no es asi?

Comment: Lo que hago es recorrer un directorio que pasamos como argumento, quitar de la salida los ficheros . y .. y ya buscar en el ls-l los permisos, el nombre del usuario, el nombre del grupo, la fecha de ultima modificacion y el nombre del fichero. No sé si me explico bien.

Comment: Cierto, esto es C clásico, del de toda la vida, sin `++` ni *hashtag* ni florituras de esas ;-)

Comment: Perdon, se me coló la almohadilla, es c clásico.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade el código desde donde llamas a `lsl()` y `lsx()`.

Comment: Ya lo he añadido

Comment: Cuando te da el error ¿se llega a mostrar algo en pantalla? ¿Falla al llamar a lsl() o al llamar a lsx()? (Entiendo que solo la llamada a lsl) Seria bueno que dentro de lsl comprobaras los posibles errores que pueden devolver stat, getpwuid o getgrgid (getpwuid devuelve null en caso de error y te deja el código de error en errno: [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getpwuid.html])

Answer (score 0):

Da violación de segmento solamente cuando le pasas como argumento un directorio inexistente; normal, porque no lo compruebas en ningún momento.

Modifica

```
if(argv[1]==NULL){
 lsx(opendir("."));
 lsl(opendir("."));
} else {
 lsx(opendir(argv[1]));
 lsl(opendir(argv[1]));
}
```

para que comprueba la existencia del directorio

```
if( argv[1] != NULL ) {
  DIR *path = opendir( argv[1] );
  if( ! path ) {
    printf( "El directorio no existe\n" );
  } else {
   lsx( path );
   lsl( path );
 }
}
```

La no comprobación del retorno de las funciones trae cosas como esa. Acostúmbrate a comprobarlo **todo**, hasta lo que *es imposible que falle*.

EDITO

Como se te ha comentado antes (yo y otros), comprueba el retorno de todas las funciones que usas.

Este código **fallará** siempre que el archivo pertenezca a un usuario inexistente (comprobado):

```
pass=getpwuid(otra.st_uid);
printf("%-8.8s\t",pass->pw_name);
grp = getgrgid(otra.st_gid);
printf("%-8.8s\t", grp->gr_name);
```

Cámbialo por, por ejemplo:

```
pass=getpwuid(otra.st_uid)
printf("%-8.8s\t", pass ? pass->pw_name : "**" );

grp = getgrgid(otra.st_gid);
printf("%-8.8s\t", grp ? grp->gr_name : "**" );
```

y revisa el resto del código, por si hay alguna llamada a función de la que no compruebas el retorno.

Comment: Tenías razón, me faltaba esa comprobación. Aún así me sigue fallando y no sé por qué. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he conseguido, el problema estaba aquí. Había que meter otra comprobación como me faltaba antes.

```
if ((pass = getpwuid(otra.st_uid)) != NULL){
                printf(" %-8.8s", pass->pw_name);
            }else{
                    printf(" %-8d", otra.st_uid);
            }
            /* Realizamos el nombre del grupo del fichero con la estructura group */
            if ((grp = getgrgid(otra.st_gid)) != NULL){
                printf(" %-8.8s", grp->gr_name);
            }else{
                printf(" %-8d", otra.st_gid);
            }
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda. Me tendré que fijar más en las comprobaciones y posibles salidas.